# Android RecyclerView reloading the activity to update data vs notifyDataSetChanged efficiency?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that in onCreate calls an API and populates a RecyclerView with product names, current stock, and an EditText to insert a value for each product.

You can then hit an add or subtract button at the top of the activity and all products with an inserted value will have their stock updated in the database by the given values via the API.

I do not pass the on screen stock values to the API (as another user may have changed it in the meantime), simply the inserted values, product ids and whether to increment/decrement the database value.

Currently, after I send the update request and it is successful, I call finish() and just reload the activity to get the updated data.

I'm wondering if it would be better to make an API call for the data after the update request and then just update the RecyclerView, it would almost be duplicate code of the onCreate but would prevent reloading the activity.

Does anyone have any insight as to the efficiency of this vs reloading the activity? It seems like reloading would be the more inefficient option but i'm not too sure.

Comment: reloading the activity is never a solution. Instead you should modify the dataset of adapter and call the desire variant of `notify` on adapter . You can alternatively use `DiffUtils` for better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume in your `onCreate` method you have something like this:

```java
onCreate() {
  setContentView(xx);
  callApiGetDataAndSetDataToRecyclerView();
}
```

If so, pls try to change the code like below `after I send the update request and it is successful`:

```java
doAfterUpdateRequestSuccessful() {
  List<Object> latestData = callApiGetData() // this should not be in the ui thread, I believe you are clear about it but just want to repeat
  recyclerViewAdapter.setData(latestData);
  recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then your recycler view will be updated with latest data.

And like @ADM's comment, `finish` and `recreate` the activity is never a solution for updating recycler view, the ux will be very very bad.

Comment: I added a method to my adapter to replace the dataset and call notifyDataSetChanged(), now I am not reloading the activity at all. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Reload the activity is not so efficient. You should instead move your fetch data and render logic to an independent method and invoke this method from onCreate and every time you want to refresh the rendered data.